# Synapse LDAPSend library requires username = Domain\User

Tags: delphi, active-directory

I'm using Synapse LDAPSend.pas library to connect and authenticate in an Active Directory server. The code is pretty simple and direct, but the problem is that the username needs "DomainName\Username" or "Username@DomainName" format to bind command works correctly. Are there anyhow to make it work only with Username specified?

```
var
  ldap: TLDAPsend;
begin
  ldap:= TLDAPsend.Create;
  try
    ldap.TargetHost := '192.168.0.12';
    ldap.UserName:= 'AD\Owner'; //here I need to specify only Owner
    ldap.Password:= 'Password!';
    if ldap.Login then
      if ldap.Bind then
      begin
        //do stuff
        ldap.Logout;
      end;
  finally
    ldap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I was thinking maybe something like "*\Owner", or any other command from Active Directory to make it works? Or maybe a Synapse setting to make it.

Comment: You are connecting against an Active Directory, which always has a name. If you know the user name, acquiring the domain name should not be a problem.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Active Directory. Is possible to get the domain name without being logged? How can I do that?

Comment: Is your program running on the client machine or on a server somewhere on the network? If the program is running on the server: is the server part of the AD domain?

Comment: The program is running on a client machine. And the big problem is: sometimes it can run outside the LAN... I'm going nuts with this! Thinking to pay some freelancer to do this with IndyTCPClient, without the need of domain in user, I know it's possible, but I have no time to study the LDAP protocol, which looks more like a big mess.

Comment: I'm looking the Synapse source code, and looks like it just do the normal TCP operations to connect/authenticate into the server. I can't understand why the DOMAIN is needed with the username on this library. Functions like Win32 AdsOpenObject doesn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

If the current user is logged on to the domain there is a variety of options to retrieve the domain name. The easiest way is to read the environment variable `USERDOMAIN` using the function [`SysUtils.GetEnvironmentVariable`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.GetEnvironmentVariable). There are also the Windows API functions [`NetWkstaUserGetInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370670(v=vs.85).aspx) available on Windows NT and better as well as [`GetUserNameEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435(v=vs.85).aspx) introduced with Windows 2000 among a lot of others, which are usually harder to use.

If your version of Delphi does not contain declarations for these API functions please use the [Jedi Windows API headers](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are there anyway to get the domain if the current user is not logged on the domain, and outside the local network? Maybe doing the login/bind anonymously on AD server and retrieve the domain name anonymously?

Comment: Try calling [`DsGetDcName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675983(v=vs.85).aspx) to retrieve a domain name. A domain controller must be able to service the request.